# SQL Hardcoded pivoting of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have some invoices tax analysis "vertically" and I need to "pivot" them.
I am using SQL Server 2008R2

Simplified example with code:

A "vertical" results example

```
15  9   NET     112.07  1/5156
15  9   VAT9    17.93   1/5156
26  18  NET     4.29    1/5157
26  18  VAT18   1.38    1/5157
```

Code to recreate it:

```
CREATE TABLE #dummy
(department_id      numeric(10,0),
 vat_category_id    numeric(10,0),
 amount_category    char(5),
 amount             numeric(10,2),
 invoice_no         char(10))

INSERT #yy VALUES(15,   9,  'NET',  112.07, '1/5156')
INSERT #yy VALUES(15,   9,  'VAT9', 17.93,  '1/5156')
INSERT #yy VALUES(26,   18, 'NET',  4.29,   '1/5157')
INSERT #yy VALUES(26,   18, 'VAT18',1.38,   '1/5157')
```

How it should be broken down:

```
CREATE TABLE #pivot
(department_id              numeric(10,0),
 net_amount                 numeric(10,0),
 vat_category_id9_amount    numeric(10,2),
 vat_category_id18_amount   numeric(10,2),
 gross_amount               numeric(10,2))
```

Sample example of the requested outcome:

```
1/5156  112.07      17.93       null    130
1/5157  4.29        null        1.38    5,67
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: use the PIVOT operator....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `conditional` aggregation :

```
select invoice_no,
       sum(case when amount_category = 'NET' then amount else 0 end),
       sum(case when amount_category = 'VAT9' then amount else 0 end),
       sum(case when amount_category = 'VAT18' then amount else 0 end),
       sum(amount)
from #dummy d
group by invoice_no;
```